# redirecting to a different webpage depending on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have a Form that redirects to a different Web Page when it gets submitted but also adds the input of a text input to the URL parameters. Example: currently on the website example.com typing in "test" into the **text input -> Submitted -> Redirected** to `example.com/newpage/test`. How would I go on about that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h2zLw4g8/ (this is two problems: 1) handle a form using JS 2) change the browser's location with JS. Both are simple, solved problems with tons of existing answers; please do some basic research before posting a question here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Here !!!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function()
  {
    var domain="html";
    var user_input=document.getElementById("url").value;
    var page=user_input.concat(domain);  
    window.location.href = '/'+page;
    };
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="">
<button id="btn">Go!</button>
```